# pronoun order where subject and object are equal

Tags: grammaticality

Is the following sentence correct? Does it sound awkward?

*It wasn't long before he and Dolores were locking eyes.*

Comment: There actually is no object in that subclause. *He and Dolores* is your subject.

Comment: Actually, the object of the clause _he and Dolores were locking eyes_ is _eyes_. And _eyes_ is not _equal_ (do you mean _identical_ or _having the same value_?) to the subject _he and Dolores_.

Comment: Yes, I see my error in terms of trying to think of a catchy title.  For dramatic effect I implied an object/subject split where grammatically there was none.  Still, if you knew Dolores like I know Dolores, you would conclude that the subject and the object were definitely equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's correct. The subject, "He and Dolores", is plural and the use of "were" is correct. As a test for the correct use of the pronoun "He" the sentence can be stated while leaving the second part of the subject Dolores off. For example: It wasn't long before him was locking eyes. Right away one can tell that using "him" in the sentence would sound awkward. Thus, restating the phrase, It wasn't long before "he" was locking eyes sounds grammatically correct. Finally, by substituting back with the proper verb tense, one can see that "He" and Dolores were locking eyes is correct.

Comment: Thank you.  I think what confused me is when I tested the sentence in my head, I tested it using "were."  Now I see I can test the sentence in the singular "was."   I am going to bookmark this address.